# ILogger: how to avoid doing heavy work if the info is not really logged

Tags: c#

I am using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.

If I have:

```
private readonly ILogger<App> _log;
_log.LogTrace(SomeHeavySerialization(someHeavyObject));
```

How can I avoid execute `SomeHeavySerialization(someHeavyObject)` if the selected logging level is bigger than "trace"?

For example:

```
var logLevel = _log.GetLogLevel_ThisFunctionDoesNotReallyExist();
if(logLevel <= theOneThatIWant)
    _log.LogTrace(SomeHeavySerialization(someHeavyObject));
```

Comment: [Ahem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger.isenabled)

Comment: @Blorgbeard Ah ok: so I can do `_log.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Trace) { _log.LogTrace(SomeHeavySerialization(someHeavyObject)) }`. That's perfect, thanks.